# SQL Server 2016 - Log rotation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am working with SQL Server 2016 and TFS 2018.
In my TFS I have a collection : DefaultCollection.
This collection has a log file (DefaultCollection_Log) which is growing fast.

I'd like to set a time period (let's say 2 weeks for examples) for log retention. This is, every day (for example)  SQL Server should delete data in my DefaultCollection_Log file older than 2 weeks.

How can I acomplish that?

Comment: Configure a backup plan so that the logs are automatically backed up and truncated.

Comment: @fr0zt, was your question addressed?. If so,  can you please mark it as answered?

Comment: ok ok, Done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction log backups to be configured. In this case, virtual log files will be reused, so transaction log file will not grow unless long-running transactions.

Note, that you have to setup backup routines **using TFS Administration Console**, regular backups using T-SQL scripts are not sufficient, because of multi-database restore in TFS.

#### Process in few steps:

1. Create scheduled backups:

[image]

2. Provide a path where backups to be stored

[image]

3. Include transaction log backups into a configuration:

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/_img/sched-backup-wiz-preconfig.png]

[SQL Server Transaction Log Architecture and Management Guide:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

> Log truncation occurs automatically after the following events, except when delayed for some reason:
>
> - Under the simple recovery model, after a checkpoint.
> - Under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, **after a log backup**, if a checkpoint has occurred since the previous
>   backup.

Comment: So, configuring a backup plan like in this case, for 30 days, I will only have the log for the last 30 days. Is this correct? Meaning that the log will alwaYS BE replaced for the 30 days log.

Comment: True, you have to configure backups of logs and set a frequent interval, for instance, every 30 minutes. Extra link with architecture of transaction logs was added to the answer